# How to get a unique row of a table's <tr> and count them all with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, sql

I have a table which is generated in a loop as shown below. With my code, a new id is given to the  after the inner loop finish executing (i.e. finish displaying a set of row) so the id is given in sets not to individual rows. My question is how can I count the total number or rows / set of rows that has a unique id for their . I know i can get the total number of row with:

```
var rowCount = $('#riskForm tr').length;
```

Here is my code:

```
<table width="850" bgcolor="white" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" class="riskForm" id="riskForm">
<thead>
<th> i </th>
<th style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">&nbsp;Importance?</th>
<th> Equal </th>
<th> How Much More </th>
</thead>

for ($i=0; $i < (sizeOf ($myArray)); $i++){ //loop through the whole table body 
$currentObs = $myArray[$i]['ObstacleDescription']; //set pointer to my current obstacle value
$x = 0;
for ($j=1; $j <= (sizeOf($myArray)-1); $j++){ //loop through the inner table
    $next = $myArray[$j]['ObstacleDescription'];
    $or = " or ";
    if (!($currentObs == $next)){
    ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $myArray[$i]['ComplianceID']; ?>">
        <td valign='center'> <?php echo $x+1; ?> </td>
        <?php $x++; ?>
        <td>
        <?php echo 
        "<input type='radio' name='op[$j]' value='0' class='myradio'>"." ".$currentObs
        ?>
        </td>

        <td><?php echo
        $or." "."<input type='radio' name='op[$j]' value='1' class='myradio'>"." ".$next;
        ?>
        </td>
        <td><small>
        <?php echo  " 1 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='1' class='myradio'>"; ?>

        </small></td>
        <td><small>
        <?php echo 
        " 2 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='2' class='myradio'>".
        " 3 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='3' class='myradio'>".
        " 4 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='4' class='myradio'>".
        " 5 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='5' class='myradio'>".
        " 6 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='6' class='myradio'>".
        " 7 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='7' class='myradio'>".
        " 8 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='8' class='myradio'>".
        " 9 "."<input type='radio' name='Intense[$j]' value='9' class='myradio'>";
        ?>

        </small></td>
    <?php    }
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><hr style='border:0; height:0px' /></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><hr style='border:0; height:0px' /></td></tr>";
}
echo "</tr>";
?>
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would also like to get the radio options of each selected row using jquery.

Comment: Put a class on the rows you want to group together

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... so there should not be more than 1 element with the same ID

Comment: You can use a `class`/custom `data-*` attribute to group similar elements

Comment: could you please give a code example of this. Im assuming the class name would change each time i go out of the inner loop? thanks

Comment: please don't post a bunch of server code when issue is client side....just post raw html . First it removes code irrelavant to the issue, plus it makes it possible for people to copy the html to demo sites and help provide working solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SInce all ID's must be  unique using a `data-row_id` attribute  on `<tr>` you could do:

JS

```
var rows=[];

$('#riskForm tr').each(function(){
   var id=$(this).data('row_id');
   if( rows.indexOf( id) ==-1){ /* push to array if it doesn't exist */
       rows.push( id)
   }
});

var totalUnique= rows.length
```

HTML

```html
<tr data-row_id="654">
```

Question about radio options is not very clear

Comment: Oh sorry for confusion. I meant each row has a set of radio buttons with values 1-9 and another set to choose out of two options. so for every row, a user will click only two radio button. what i would like to do is get the values of each clicked radio buttons. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i just implemented your code now and it just gives me thesame id for all the rows.

Comment: you need to use php to set `data-row_id`. Look at this for radios...not sure what format you want  http://jsfiddle.net/k58nh/1

Comment: just thought of much simpler approach for radios...wrap table in a form and use `serialize()` or `serializeArray()` depending on your needs

Comment: Thank you so much @charlietfl , but could you please provide an example of how to use this serializeArray()? sorry but im practically new to php/scripting.

Comment: one last question sorry. is there a way to create a nXn matrix table with the values of each rows' radio button that is checked? Please refer to this link for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446115/constructing-a-nxn-matrix-table-from-users-input. thanks

Comment: yes but don't see any value in it....you only need to know if one is checked or not, and value of the checked one

Comment: Yes. you're right. but my problem is creating a matrix according to the selected radios. i have no idea how to code this i.e. create a multidimensional array and store results in a matrix table